# generate alert only if change took place

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

i have a table with a `<contenteditable>` `<td>`, and i want to create alert only when change took place but i cant get it to work...when i try to compare value i end up comparing it to himself (i think) and alert always happens.
this is my function:

```
$scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat){
        var pre = cronFormat;
        $.post("updateCronChange.php","user_id="+userId+"&script_id="+scriptId+"&cron_format="+cronFormat, function(data){
        $scope.demoData = userId + scriptId + cronFormat;
        angular.equals(pre,cronFormat){
        alert("user script settings table update the cron format to:"+cronFormat);}
    });
}
```

and this is my table:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-

    controller="tableCtrl">
                <thead>
                <th>user name</th>
                <th>script name</th>
                <th>cron format<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Min|Hour|Day Of Month|Month|Day Of Week"></span></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,script_id) in data">
                    <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in script_id">
                        <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
                        <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
<td class="cronFormat"><input type="text" ng-model="cron_format" ng-blur="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)"/></td>                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the function being called whenever moustout of the input field..how can i make it show the alert only when user changed the data in cron_format?

**UPDATED THE FUNCTION**

Comment: Presenting the code in jsFiddle is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use old and new value in watch:-

```
$scope.$watch('data.cronFormat',function(new,old){
 if(new!=old){
alert('it has changed');
}
});
```

And instead use ng-change in the place of ng-blur :)

Comment: "changed the data" Please explain this line what do you mean by this statement ?

Comment: lets say cron_format `<td>` contains value of "test" and user changed the value inside this `<td>` to "test2" only than alert should pop-up, but if he only clicked on the field but didnt change the value, alert shouldn't pop-up

Comment: in that case store very first value of model into variable(intial) and then in $watch compare new!=intital in that case alert will be visible :-)

Comment: my bad it works...using the word new was the problem..thanks!

Comment: sry actually that was my bad i should remember new is reserved keyword :-P
Glad it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this to the cron format row

```
<td class="cronFormat"><input type="text" ng-model="data.cronFormat"></td>
```

and use this for your javascript:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.$watch('data.cronFormat',function(){
 alert('something is happening');
});
```

this will watch data.cronFormat for changes and update you every change, the ng-model binds your input to a $scope variable. and you should add data. to prevent trouble if you should use directives, read this for more https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

if you need only when it is fully changed you could try it like this

```
<td class="cronFormat"><input type="text" ng-model="data.cronFormat" ng-focus="storeOld()" ng-blur="checkNew()"></td>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.data = {} 
var old = '';
$scope.storeOld = function(){
   old = $scope.data.cronFormat;
};
$scope.checkNew = function(){
   if(old != $scope.data.cronFormat){
        alert('it has changed');
   }
};
```

this will store old value when the user selects the input and check if it has changed when the user leaves the input.

Comment: correct me if im wrong but that will alert every time something is happening and not when user actually changed the value of cron_format

Comment: yes this will alert every change of data.cronFormat, so if a user types 12 characters you will get 12 alerts if that isn't what you'd like you could use ng-blur

Comment: added new method @johnking

Comment: but can i use two ng-blur? i already run saveCron() in ng-blur

Comment: you could call that function from within checkNew(). you could also use ng-blur="checkNew(); saveCron()" but the first seems more appropiate since you check if it changed @johnking

Comment: agree, problem is ng-watch wont wait for cursor to leave the input field